# it is possible to run docker container on marathon with Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mesos, marathon

In order to run docker container on Marathon,
I install the dockerToolBox.

I start mesos-slave with

`containerizers=docker,mesos --executor_registration_timeout=5mins`

Then I post an App with docker container to Marathon.

And the mesos-slave told me :

```
I1218 16:16:18.569870 251678720 containerizer.cpp:1284] Executor for container '3ca60aeb-0a15-4b93-9ff2-b09c9aa4a610' has exited
I1218 16:16:18.569905 251678720 containerizer.cpp:1097] Destroying container '3ca60aeb-0a15-4b93-9ff2-b09c9aa4a610'
Failed to perform recovery: Collect failed: Failed to 'docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps -a': exit status = exited with status 1 stderr = Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

so i excute `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps -a` on my mac , it told me the same error
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?`

then i excute `docker-machine ssh default` into the VM ,
and excute `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps -a` , it works.

is it mean that it is impossible run docker containner on marathon with Mac Os beacause of Mac Os use the VM to run docker ???

Comment: To run `docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps -a` in mac i think you need to use `export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2375` then docker will figure out where the daemon is running.

Comment: I configured Docker Machine using `eval $(docker-machine env machine-name)` and all `DOCKER_*` variables are set. But still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: when running docker with marathon ,  it will request docker unix socket, like "docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ps -a" , in mac os , we start the docker by VM , the `docker.sock`  is in the VM ,   so , I think it is impossible to do that